# Zend Framework Zend_Controller_Router_Route (catch all controllers before routing param)

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

My apologies for the title of this question not being very descriptive but the truth is I'm not too sure what the correct terminology for this question is. I am new to using Zend Framework.

Imagine this url: www.foo.com/bar
The code below takes "bar" and passes it through to the index controller's load action. However I have another controller called "mypresentation" which is getting ignored now the router below has been added to the Bootstrap.

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    '/:prospect',
    array('controller'=>'index', 'action' => 'load'));

$router->addRoute('load', $route);
```

How to I make the router ignore hardcoded controllers ?

Any help is much appreciated and I'll change the title if I can when I have more information.

Alex.

FIX:

```
$prospectRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    '/:prospect',
    array('controller'=>'index', 'action' => 'load')
);

$route2 = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'mypresentation',                        
     array('controller' => 'mypresentation') 
);

$router->addRoute('index', $prospectRoute);
$router->addRoute('mypresentation', $route2);
```

Comment: So you want the default routes + this one custom route (as a basic catch-all)?  The problem is your defined route intercepts all `'/whatever'` first...  Maybe it can be chained to match after the default routes are checked.

Comment: I have tried making it chain to match after the defaults but with no luck. You understand the question though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another route before this one, to catch any routes to the mypresentation controller first. It runs through the routes in order till it finds the first one it matches.

```
$route2 = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'mypresentation',                        // what's typed in URL
     array('controller' => 'mypresentation') // send here
);

$router->addRoute('mypresentation', $route2);
$router->addRoute('load', $route);           // Your original route
```

If you want to catch all controllers, use

```
$route3 = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    ':controller',                       
     array('controller' => ':controller')
);
```

Comment: I think I would like to catch all the controllers so your third example is what I am after however having put this code and $router->addRoute('index', $route3) before the code I originally posted hasn't changed the outcome.